# Two-way event binding doesn't work inside form tag Angular 2

Tags: forms, input, angular2-forms, two-way-binding, angular2-ngmodel

I have a `form` which has an `input`. I applied two-way event binding on the `input`, however, it doesn't work. I have imported the `FormsModule` in my `AppModule` and I am not getting any errors.

`search.component.html`:

```html
<form>
  <h1>{{ query }}</h1>
  <input [(ngModel)]="query">
</form>
```

`search.component.ts`:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.scss']
})
export class SearchComponent {
  public query: string;
  
  constructor() {}
}
```

It **works** when I do *not* include the `form` tag:

```html
<h1>{{ query }}</h1>
<input [(ngModel)]="query">
```

But I need to use `form` for submission. Any ideas what's wrong?

Relevant [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41258343/two-way-data-binding-in-form-doesnt-work-angular-2).

Answer (score 0):

I got the following error later, not sure why it didn't show up earlier:

```
ERROR Error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form
      control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.

      Example 1: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" name="first">
      Example 2: <input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
    at Function.missingNameException (forms.js:4716)
    at NgModel._checkName (forms.js:5050)
    at NgModel._checkForErrors (forms.js:5033)
    at NgModel.ngOnChanges (forms.js:4956)
    at NgModel.rememberChangeHistoryAndInvokeOnChangesHook (core.js:2197)
    at callHook (core.js:3109)
    at callHooks (core.js:3075)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:3027)
    at refreshView (core.js:7333)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:8465)
```

As suggested, I resolved it by adding `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"`:

```html
<form>
  <h1>{{ query }}</h1>
  <input [(ngModel)]="query" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
</form>
```

You could also choose the second route as specified, i.e., add a `name` attribute and put anything:

```html
<form>
  <h1>{{ query }}</h1>
  <input [(ngModel)]="query" name="something">
</form>
```